# Some questions about strings

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string, initialization

I encountered a problem. In the following code, I expected the length of the string p to be 3, but the actual length is 6. This is the first place I wonder. Then, when I debug myself, the length of the debugged p is in line with the expected result. This makes me feel very puzzled. I do n’t know why the length of p is 6, and why the length becomes 3 when debugging. . Can someone answer this question?

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    char p[]={'a','b','c'}, q[10] = {'a','b','c'};
    printf("%p  %p\n",&q,&p);
    printf("%d  %d\n",strlen(q),strlen(p));
    return 0;
}
```

[pic-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I56jK.png)
[pic-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ud74T.png)

Comment: `p` is not null-terminated; `strlen` keeps counting until it sees a null (or your program is aborted because you access memory that is not yours).

Comment: You are using `strlen` on `p`, and `p` does not fulfill the contract for using `strlen`, which leads to undefined behavior.  With undefined behavior, anything can happen.  The program may have nonsensical results.  It may appear to work correctly.  It may crash.  Or any other behavior that would otherwise be inexplicable.

Comment: Note that `q` is initialized, and any array elements not provided in the initializer are set to null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, `p` is not a null-terminated character array, so it cant be used as a *string*. Using this as argument to function calls which expect a *string*, will cause [undefined behaviour (UB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The output of a program containing UB cannot be justified in any manner.

To add some more context, `q` is null-terminated, as per the rule of initializer list having less argument than the size of aggregate, the remaining members get initialized as if they had static storage, so in case of `char` type, they get initialized with `0` (which is the null terminator needed for a string). So, using `q` as a string is fine.

**Solution:**

You can either

- mention a dimension more than that of the elements of the initializer list
- put a null value as the last element n the initializer list `{'a','b','c', '\0'}`
- use a *string* (instead of initializer list) to initialize the array, like `"abc"`, which will include the null terminator in the array.

Comment: thank you.In fact, this question is an exam question, my choice is 3 and 3. It seems that the question may not be rigorous

Comment: Okay, I confirmed the question again. The correct answer mentions that the length of p is unknown and the length of q is 3.

Comment: @tangger Yeah, there you go.

Comment: @tangger - Actually the question is rigorous.   The calculation of `strlen(p)` gives undefined behaviour.   Also, `strlen()` returns a `size_t` - which is an unsigned type - so printing it using `%d` (which expects to be supplied an `int`, and has undefined behaviour if an `int` is not passed) also gives undefined behaviour.   So 3 and 3 is not a guaranteed output.   In fact, if you gave an answer that ANY particular output is expected, then your answer was incorrect.   Getting different behaviour between debugging and release builds is a typical (not guaranteed) symptom of undefined behaviour

Answer (score 2):

In C, strings have to end with a null byte, and that's how `strlen` finds their length. Declare your strings like this and the length will show up properly:

```c
char p[]={'a','b','c', '\0'}, q[10] = {'a','b','c', '\0'};
```

Comment: Or `char p[]="abc", q[10] = "abc";`

Comment: Note that `q` was already correct - for arrays, `{}` initialize as many elements as were provided and rest is zero-initialized. `char q[10] = {'a','b','c'};` is guaranteed to have `a`, `b`, `c` and 7 zeroes in it.

Answer (score 1):

`p` is not null-terminated; `strlen` keeps counting until it sees a null (or your program is aborted because you access memory that is not yours).

Note that `q` *is* initialized, and any array elements not provided in the initializer are set to null.